# Can't create Distribution Provisioning Profile! "Please create a Distribution Certificate"!

Tags: iphone, xcode, distribution, profile, provisioning

I have an active distribution certificate.

But when I go to create Distribution Provisioning profile I see "Please create a Distribution Certificate" in Distribution Certificate field:
[image]

But when I go to create Development Provisioning Profile The Certificate field contain an active Development certificate.

When I go to this link "Please create a Distribution Certificate", I see the following screen, but after that, how to submit the certificate, the page just reloaded and nothing happens.
[image]

Please, help me! Thank you!

Comment: Just to check.. Did you actually follow through with the process outlined in the (http://i.stack.imgur.com/ls6C1.jpg) page? i.e. generate the CSR as requested, and upload it?

Comment: read this Document http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#technotes/tn2250/_index.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/DTS40009933

Comment: Madhumal Gunetileke, yes I did. But I already have a dist certificate, and I've used it before

Answer (score 0):

hey when you go to create development profile have you browse the certificate ( generated by key chain access) by clicking the browse file button at lower left corner after browsing then you click the submit button then you get the distribution certificate.
follow the steps given below link:
http://mobiforge.com/developing/story/deploying-iphone-apps-real-devices

Comment: I don't have problem with development certificate! Only with distribution.

Answer (score 0):

Best approach would be to remove every certificate / profile which has to do with "developer" or "Xcode" in the Keychain Access. Then, join the provisioning portal and do all the steps on the left from up to down.

Download the certificate from the apple portal, create your own certificate and upload this one on the site you are on in your question. This should do the trick.

I also had this problem, because there was more than one developer profile installed on my laptop which crashed everything.

Comment: If I remove the certificates, what will happen to those applications that are already posted in the app store?

Comment: Nothing. The certificates stay the same. You just sign your computer __again__ with them. (Don't delete them in the Prov. Portal, just on your Mac.)

Comment: I don't understand you. I have old dist prov. profiles that contain dist. certificate. But I can't create new dist. prov. profile, because I don't see old dist cert and can't create new dist. cert. I want remove old dis. cert. and try create it again. But what heppened with old dist. prov. profiles if I do it. Why it depend on my computer? If I dowload dist cert. again why it help to create dist. prov. profile.... sorry for my English)